# Problemas de render Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, xml

¡Hola! Tengo un error y quisiera pedir por favor la ayuda de alguien. Bueno... Sucede que en mi proyecto de Android Studio aparece el siguiente error al momento de ver el preview de las vistas: Render Problem.

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.lambda$createViewFromCustomInflater$0(BridgeInflater.java:259)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromCustomInflater(BridgeInflater.java:285)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.onCreateView(BridgeInflater.java:122)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:928)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:948)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1002)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:309)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1121)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1095)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1124)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1095)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1124)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1095)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1124)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1095)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:499)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:353)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:431)
at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:141)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:714)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$7(RenderTask.java:870)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderExecutor$runAsyncActionWithTimeout$2.run(RenderExecutor.kt:187)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
at java.base/java.lang.StringLatin1.charAt(StringLatin1.java:47)
at java.base/java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:693)
at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getType(BridgeTypedArray.java:1027)
at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getType(BridgeTypedArray.java:812)
at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getValue(BridgeTypedArray.java:781)
at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.peekValue(BridgeTypedArray.java:850)
at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:5951)
at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:996)
at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:87)
at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:83)
at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText.<init>(AppCompatEditText.java:93)
at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText.<init>(AppCompatEditText.java:88)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createEditText(AppCompatViewInflater.java:209)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:127)
... 39 more
```

El segundo error que aparece es String Index out of range: -1 Error inflating the preview.

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
at java.base/java.lang.StringLatin1.charAt(StringLatin1.java:47)
at java.base/java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:693)
at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getType(BridgeTypedArray.java:1027)
at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getType(BridgeTypedArray.java:812)
at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getValue(BridgeTypedArray.java:781)
at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.peekValue(BridgeTypedArray.java:850)
at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:5951)
at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:697)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:99)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView.<init>(MockView.java:55)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView.<init>(MockView.java:51)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView.<init>(MockView.java:47)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:324)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1121)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1095)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1124)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1095)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1124)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1095)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1124)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1095)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:499)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:353)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:431)
at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:141)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:714)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$7(RenderTask.java:870)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderExecutor$runAsyncActionWithTimeout$2.run(RenderExecutor.kt:187)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

No sé qué hacer, sale la sugerencia de refrescar la vista pero no funciona, simplemente continúa el problema, ya hice lo que ponen en otros foros y no funciona o simplemente no aplica para mi problema. Lo gracioso es que cuando lo ejecuto, funciona normalmente. Espero que alguien pueda ayudarme, muchas gracias! Dejo el código del Layout, cabe resaltar que pasa lo mismo con todos los layouts:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ui.fragment.LoginFragment"
android:fillViewport="true"
>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/constraintLayout2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/border_layout"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:labelFor="@id/editTextIdentification"
                android:text="@string/identification"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextIdentification"
                style="@style/font_input"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
                android:autofillHints=""
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint=""
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
                tools:text="1075220291" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtViewIdentificationError"
                style="@style/font_error"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextIdentification"
                tools:text="error"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:labelFor="@id/editTextPassword"
                android:text="@string/password"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtViewIdentificationError" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextPassword"
                style="@style/font_input"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
                android:autofillHints=""
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint=""
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2"
                tools:text="123456" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtViewPasswordError"
                style="@style/font_error"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextPassword"
                tools:text="error"/>

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtViewPasswordError">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView7"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/recover_password"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/recoverItHerebtn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                    android:text="@string/recover_it_here"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView7"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/getIntoBtn"
                style="@style/button"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
                android:text="@string/get_into"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/dark_gray"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.501"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:text="@string/register_here"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout2"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/signUpBtn"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="@string/sign_up"
            style="@style/button"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/dark_gray"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: Hola, comparte el codigo de tu layout. De esta manera podremos ver cual puede ser el error.

Comment: @Quimbo Listo! Ya lo agregué a la publicación

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes probar eliminando las propiedades `android:autofillHints=""` del layout o los layouts donde los tengas o colocandole un valor por defecto como "testHint" o "no". Ejemplo: `android:autofillHints="no"`

Esto puede ser lo que esté causando el problema.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Ese era el problema!